# How to enable the comments to have resolved (unresolved) flag by default in a gerrit project

Tags: gerrit

I am using Gerrit Code Review (2.14.9)

Gerrit provides option to fetch the unresolved comments using the search option

```
has:unresolved.
```

But when I search in of my projects, even though I add comments, I donot see the option to set it "unresolved" nor set an existing comment to resolved.

Is there any option to enable resolved checkbox (which I saw in the latest gerrit review 
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/q/has:unresolved

I search in of my projects, even though I add comments, I donot see the option to set it "unresolved" nor set an existing comment to resolved.

```
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/q/has:unresolved
```

Request

```
GET /changes/myProject~master~I8473b95934b5732ac55d26311a706c9c2bde9940/comments HTTP/1.0
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Disposition: attachment
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

  )]}'
  {
    "gerrit-server/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/server/project/RefControl.java": [
      {
        "patch_set": 1,
        "id": "TvcXrmjM",
        "line": 23,
        "message": "[nit] trailing whitespace",
        "updated": "2013-02-26 15:40:43.986000000"
        "author": {
          "_account_id": 1000096,
          "name": "John Doe",
          "email": "john.doe@example.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "patch_set": 2,
        "id": "TveXwFiA",
        "line": 49,
        "in_reply_to": "TfYX-Iuo",
        "message": "Done",
        "updated": "2013-02-26 15:40:45.328000000"
        "author": {
          "_account_id": 1000097,
          "name": "Jane Roe",
          "email": "jane.roe@example.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Even when the response is received with the flag unresolved,

```
"file.mk": [{
            "author": {
                "_account_id": 1172,
                "name": "Person Name",
                "email": "email@server.com",
                "username": "username"
            },
            "patch_set": 14,
            "id": "2b4f392f_6c36a0ae",
            "line": 70,
            "updated": "2019-09-18 02:42:23.000000000",
            "message": "this is not required.",
            "unresolved": false
        },
```

I never get the unresolved flag to be true.

Is there any option to enable it?

Comment: Are you using the new Polygerrit UI? I think the option to resolve/unresolve comments only exist in the new UI.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira,
We use the Gerrit which is centrally deployed by our IT team and we don't have an option to modify the UI.

Which is the version of the new UI do you think the option is enabled?

(We are using 2.16.17 version now)

Comment: The PolyGerrit was deployed for the first time on Gerrit 2.14, but it was not the default UI at that time. The PolyGerrit became the default UI on Gerrit 2.16.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira, the current version doesn't have it supported, probably will check in further updatest.